# Windows Small Business Server 2008 - Local Admin password

Tags: windows-sbs

I'm running Windows SBS2008 and now I need to change the local admin password. Like Windows 2000-2003 server, in Server management, I was able to change the admin password in Local user and groups. Right now, that feature is not listed.  Where might I find that feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting...  In my Server 2008 I have it listed right where you say it is (Server manager->Configureation->Local Users and Groups)...  However, there are several ways to access this, and the best way I would recommend is via mmc.

Step-by-step:

1. Win+R
2. type "mmc", hit enter
3. File->Add/Remove Snap In...
4. Scroll to Local Users and Groups in the "Available snap-ins:" box.
5. Click the "Add >" button.
6. Choose Local computer and click "Finish" button.
7. Click "OK" button.
8. Use as you normally would.

Let me know if you have any trouble.

P.S. Maybe this is a question better suited for [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com)?

Comment: Hi,

When I add "Local computer", I have to select the target machine. I chose local computer and when I hit finish, I get the following message:

The computer SERVERNAME\domain.local is a domain controller. This snap-in cannot be used on a domain controller. Domain accounts are managed with the AD Users and Computer snap-in.

I don't get it... How my local admin account can be managed from AD? This makes no sense for me.

Thanks a bunch again for you answer!
David.

Comment: I finally found the issue. When the IT manager installed SBS2008, the local "Administrator" account is not listed. SBS asked to create an admin account under another name, which was the manager's name. So now I'm not confused anymore and I know that some snap-ins cannot be installed on a DC.

Thank you very much!

Best regards,
David.